# Temp table from two functions into a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, pivot

I need to create a pivot table from two functions, because of the number of records involved in this, I want to use a temp table.

```
SELECT [OrderNumber]
    ,[OrderName]
    ,[Code]
    ,[Amount1]
 INTO #TempPayment 
FROM [dbo].[fn_Reconciliation_PaymentByDateRange](@BeginDate,@EndDate) 

SELECT [OrderNumber]
    ,[OrderName]
    ,[Code]
    ,[Amount1]
 INTO #TempInvoice
FROM [dbo].[fn_Reconciliation_InvoiceByDateRange](@BeginDate,@EndDate)
```

The above is what I was using for creating 2 temp tables, but I would like to see if I could condense it down into one temp table.

End result of this is that I need to be able to pull the "Select" portion listed above and then `pivot` them on the `Code` Column. I can handle that, but I don't really want to end up generating a 3rd Temp table, but I think I might end up needing to.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. Here:

```
SELECT [OrderNumber]
,[OrderName]
,[Code]
,[Amount1]
INTO #TempCompilation
FROM [dbo].[fn_Reconciliation_PaymentByDateRange](@BeginDate,@EndDate) 

INSERT INTO #TempCompilation
SELECT [OrderNumber]
,[OrderName]
,[Code]
,[Amount1]
FROM [dbo].[fn_Reconciliation_InvoiceByDateRange](@BeginDate,@EndDate)
```